# Windows XP automatically install default drivers

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, drivers

While ago I've installed Windows XP  on my "fail-safe" eSATA flash drive. The  installation is a little customized (this might be the cause of the problem).

The problem is that when I connect new device to PC and boot from that flash drive, it displays "New hardware" dialog for each device, where I have to click ok-ok-ok to load default or already installed drivers.

It happens even when I switch USB ports of mouse or keyboard.

Obviously, when both kbd & mouse are in different ports, I cannot click [ok] :-) Earlier I was kinda fixing this by attaching PS/2 keyboard, but right now I don't have one.

Is there something in registry to have it install default drivers for everything automatically without dialogues?

Comment: Are you plugging the drive into the same computer each time?

Comment: Most of the times yes. But as this happens rarely, configuration changes over time.

Comment: According to Microsoft, Windows can't run off of flash drives.

Comment: Windows XP can work out of USB flash drives with slight modification of driver load order. In my case, this wasn't necessary, as my flash drive is eSATA (i.e. effectively SSD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win XP/Vista/7 weren't really made to be portable, you can expect there to be problems, btw not related to the question is it an OCZ Throttle? Was going to buy one but they're discontinued now.

There won't be a way for you to install drivers automatically, the best way is, if it has even booted is to let it install the drivers each time.

Comment: Yes, it is Throttle. There are new series of eSATA/USB flash drives out there, so you will find one ;-)

I do not want to do it all automatically. Just try on your PC: unplug keyboard and plug into different USB port. It won't ask you to choose driver. In my case it chooses...